# Memory used by a process decrease when other process request a lot of memory?

Tags: python, linux, memory-management

I do not understand how the OS manage the memory of a process in some case. If a launch this script:

```py
import os, psutil, time

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(process.memory_info().rss)
```

This give me the memory used by the process (12660736 bytes for my machine).

If, at the same time, I opened a python console and tried to create a very big variable (big enough to crash the console):

```py
big_var = "-" * 10 ** 10
```

The python console crashed, and the memory used by the first process decreases (go to 9216000 bytes).

How is it possible that the second process changes the memory used by the first process ?

Comment: You should look up how virtual memory works